# Win32: How to scroll Listbox control by mouse wheel when it is not focused?

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox, listbox, mousewheel

Situation:  In a window I have 3 child control:

- 1 Textbox control: `tb`
- 2 Listbox control: `lb1` and `lb2`

When `tb` is focused, and mouse is above `lb1`, user scroll the mouse wheel.
The expected behavior is `lb1` scroll it item base on mouse event. But it doesnt.
One method is redirect mousewheel event from `tb` to `lb1`. But then I have to check if mouse is above `lb1` or `lb2`, also if window have more and more Listbox, it become heavy work, also add check to other textbox, other control.

---

So what I ask is how to scroll Listbox when have mouse wheel above it, when the listbox is not focused?

Comment: You get this behavior for free in Windows 10.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: good news, then I'll ask user switch to Windows 10 to scroll the listbox :)

Comment: That is an unreasonable thing to ask the user to do for something that trivial. Whatever the case, I doubt this is in your hands to control (unless you wish to subclass every single window you ever create and simulate input manually on each WM_MOUSEWHEEL/WM_MOUSEHWHEELs, because you cannot use `SendMessage()` on input messages). You can have the user set it for the entire system with a mouse setting whose name I forget (XMouse?) and many similar tools.